# flushleft adds empty page when used for bibliography

Tags: bibtex, vertical-alignment

I have a small problem in my thesis:

I need the Bibliography to be left-justified and used a simple \begin{flushleft} command to realize that:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}
\begin{flushleft}
\bibliography{Bibliography} 
\end{flushleft}
```

I realized though, that when adding this flushleft command, that a blank page gets created in front of the Bibliography.
Any idea as to why that is happening?

I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: I used the online editor sharelatex with a thesis template. So I made a sample - (more) minimal - project with the same problem: 
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59959ff217353839f0ed5e69

Comment: Maybe try `\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\endgroup`

Comment: or just `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright}`

Comment: Your first advice worked perfectly! Thank you very much! (I am not sure how I can accept a comment as an answer though)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry about accepting, I found another similar question, so this one will probably marked as duplicate soon. (if you agree with this, you can speed up the process by confirming the duplicate)